# Help formalizing this proof about a continuous, one-one function.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I'm having a bit of trouble getting the language on this proof right, though I think I have the idea correct.

I have the function $f\colon D \rightarrow {\bf R}$ where $D = [a,b]$. The function is continuous and one-to-one. I need to show that for $c$ in $(a,b)$, that $f(a) < f(c) < f(b)$.

Ok, so I have the general idea. Since the function  is continuous, it's image is also an interval since the domain is an interval (already proven before in the book). Then I know that if $c$ is in the interval $(a,b)$ that $f(c)$ is in the interval $(f(a),f(b))$.

I know that I need to use the fact that $f$ is one-to-one to show that since all values in the function are unique, and since the value at $b$ is larger than the one at $a$, that the function is strictly increasing. I am having trouble getting started putting this formally though with inequalities.

I wanted to start with something like

$f(a) \leq f(c)$ but that because of the one-one fact, that this has to be a strict inequality

$f(a) < f(c)$. I got into trouble with this though because I don't think I should just assume that the function is larger at $c$. It could be something like

$f(a) \geq f(c)$ for all I know.

Any helpful hints would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know that your function is increasing and not decreasing?

Comment: I don't. All I know is that f(b) > f(a). So I'm not sure what to do given an arbitrary value in between. I know I need to get that last inequality using something about the one-oneness but I don't know what it is yet... Well I know that if f(c) was to be less than f(a) that later the graph would have to rise again for f(b) to be greater than f(a), but that couldn't happen if the function was one to one. I guess I could go contradiction but I don't like that route so much

Comment: If $f$ is one-to-one on a non-empty closed interval it is either strictly increasing or decreasing. So if you know $f(b) > f(a)$ (which you didn't really mention up top) where $a < b$, then you can conclude that your function is strictly increasing. Then your conclusion follows.

Comment: Of course, continuity is also needed since there are one-to-one functions that are not strictly increasing or decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is continuous on a compact set (i.e. closed and bounded intervals in $\mathbb{R}$) it reaches $\min$ and $\max$. If the function is one to one, it is either strictly increasing or decreasing. The proof for the last statement is quite straightforward. If $f$ is strictly increasing then $f(a)$ is an absolute minimum on $D$. This can be proved by contradiction easily. Therefore $f(c)>f(a) \;\;\;\forall c \in (a,b)$. Similarly you can prove that $f(b)$ is an absolute maximum, and therefore $f(c)<f(a) \;\;\;\forall c \in (a,b)$.

It is similar when the function is strictly decreasing.

Comment: If $f$ is strictly increasing then $f(a)$ is an absolute minimum on $D$. Suppose that $f(a)$ is not an absolute minimum. Therefore there is $x_0\in(a,b)$ such that $f(x_0)$ is an absolute minimum (because we are working on a compact set and the function is strictly increasing). It follows that $f(a)>f(x_0)$ but $a<x_0$. Therefore the function $f$ is not strictly increasing $\Rightarrow \Leftarrow$. Hence $f(a)$ is a minimum.